# Default date value not showing in a Modal

Tags: html, date, modal-dialog

I have the same exact code:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="2021-04-16">
```

In the main page and in a Modal, the parameter value="2021-04-16" works in the main page, but not in the in a modal.

What am I missing here?

[https://codepen.io/Bodock/pen/oNBMbdP?editors=1010][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change (Remove animation fade)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

To

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

**OR**

remove backdrop for modal, then it will work fine with the animation as well...

```
 var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
  exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-backdrop').remove(); // SEE THIS LINE
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
  var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')
    modalTitle.textContent = 'Why: ' + recipient
    modalBodyInput.value = recipient
 })
```